# .htaccess, friendly url parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I'm trying to solve this:

control.mysite.com/?v=customers
control.mysite.com/?v=providers
control.mysite.com/?v=customers&id=1234
control.mysite.com/?v=providers&id=5678

for this:

control.mysite.com/customers
control.mysite.com/providers
control.mysite.com/customers/1234
control.mysite.com/providers/5678

I've checked what [kristen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65703/kristen) asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023298/seo-friendly-url-rewriter-parameters) but no answer yet. Also I found a lot of related questions but they have not what I'm looking for or are hard to adapt/implement.

**Edit**: *I forgot to mention that I'm running this site in a subdomain. I don't know if could affect.*

Answer (score 4):

Can you please try this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?v=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?v=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Or just refer the site below...

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: It doesn't work. It shows a 500-internal-error message (with or without parameters). I left just one rule: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?v=$1&id=$2 [L]` and needs strictly both parameters to work but disable css style (?). With just the first parameter I obtain a 404-Not-Found-error and without parameters the css style works good.